# What will be my next step to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I am totally new to Ubuntu,I have download the latest Ubuntu 12 64bit(ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso) from the Ubuntu site,the file is approx 700mb.

I want to install it on my laptop(currently on windows 7 32bit) that's why i copied the file to my usb then paste it to the c: drive of my Windows platform,(the file is in rar format) that's why i extracted it and found that there is wubi.exe (which is the Ubuntu installer for windows).

Now what should I do, do I? Just click the wubi.exe and follow the process, will wubi.exe need any internet connection to download any other extra file or 700mb is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://linuxliveusb.com) to create your USB drive bootable. Just download and install it and follow the instruction. And yes, you don't need any internet connection now for Ubuntu installation.

After making your USB bootable, boot from the USB drive and follow the on-screen installation. If you want to keep your Windows installation, choose **Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows**, or if you don't want to keep Windows then choose **Replace Windows with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**. and just follow what the installer says.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you had downloaded the Ubuntu 12 64bit iso file (ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso).  I believe that if you're running Win 7 (32 bit) then you'll need to download the [32-bit version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=12.04.4&architecture=i386) of Ubuntu.

Just a thought.

Comment: there is no problem except grub installation failure which i already figure out

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions from: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

In the right column are links to instructions of how to burn a DVD or copy to USB stick.